# Angularjs ng-model not working after defining the ng-model in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like the ng-model of an input to be created automatically based off of the name of the input it is on. This is because Html.TextBoxFor etc in MVC creates the proper name to bound the input to the server side model. To reduce user error from having to retype the exact string into the ng-model, I would like my team to just put a directive and it gets created. I found this code on stackoverflow for this.

```
datatableApp.directive('automaticangularmodelbinding', function ($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                replace: false,
                priority: 10000,
                terminal: true, // these terminal and a high priority will stop all other directive from being compiled at first run,
                scope: {
                    automaticangularmodelbinding: '@@'
                },
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {                    
                    attrs.$set('ngModel', (scope.automaticangularmodelbinding != '') ? (scope.automaticangularmodelbinding + '.' + attrs.name) : attrs.name); // set value of ng-model to be the same as the name attribute
                    attrs.$set('automaticangularmodelbinding', null); // remove itself to avoid a recusion

                    $compile(element)(scope); // begin compiling other directives
                }
            };
        });
```

This works and the ng-model is created with the name of the element. However, when I pull the data down from the server and set it, the inputs do not get filled in with the data. If I take out the automatic directive and define it normally via ng-model, it does work.

My code for the server pull down.

```
$scope.getEditStreet = function (streetID) {
                $http.post('@Url.Action(Model.GetFormControllerFunctionName, Model.GetFormControllerName)', "{ @Model.JavascriptEditPropertyName : " + streetID + "}").then(function (response) {                    
                    $scope.editFormData = response.data.ResultObject;
                    $scope.$apply();                        
                }, function (response) {
                    alert("fail" + response.statusText);
                });
            };
```

With ng-model, I needed the scope.apply call to get the checkboxes to check. After using this automatic version, scope.apply errors. If I remove scope apply though it still doesn't work even on the text boxes even though that worked before without the apply.

It seems to be the fact that I added ng-model after the fact, that it is not working the same way as it being there from the start. How can I get this to work?

**Edit:**

After reading zaitsman comments, the final version that works is as follows. I removed scope from the directive and used attrs['automaticangularmodelbinding'] for my passing of the data I needed.

```
datatableApp.directive('automaticangularmodelbinding', function ($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                replace: false,
                priority: 10000,
                terminal: true, // these terminal and a high priority will stop all other directive from being compiled at first run,
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {                    
                    attrs.$set('ngModel', (attrs['automaticangularmodelbinding'] != '') ? (attrs['automaticangularmodelbinding'] + '.' + attrs.name) : attrs.name); // set value of ng-model to be the same as the name attribute
                    attrs.$set('automaticangularmodelbinding', null); // remove itself to avoid a recusion

                    $compile(element)(scope); // begin compiling other directives
                }
            };
        });
```

Comment: Your directive declared isolated scope, because you specified `scope`. In this case, when you do the `getEditStreet` it sets `editFormData` on some other scope, because it has no access to the scope of the directive.

Do you really need isolated scope for your directive?

Comment: @zaitsman No, I don't need an isolated scope. I thought that was the syntax to allow me to add in a variable to the call. I want to be able to say <input automaticangularmodelbinding> and <div automaticangularmodelbinding="extraParameterInFront">. By putting the scope in, I was able to do that (have an optional string passed in). If that is breaking it, maybe I can't have the extra parameter?

Comment: mate parameter has absolutely nothing to do with isolated scope.

Assuming you toss out the `scope` out of your `directive`, in your `link` function you can do `var myPara = scope[attrs['automaticangularmodelbinding']];` and that will contain `extraParameterInFront` from the parent scope. If that `parameter` is just a string it is even easier: `var myPara = attrs['automaticangularmodelbinding'];`

Comment: @zaitsman Using attrs['automaticangularmodelbinding'] worked perfectly and everything is working now. If you post as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: added an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, i suggest you would skip isolated scope so that you can use variables from the declaring scope of the directive.
To access the values passed to the directive you can use the `attrs` object.

So remove `scope` from the directive completely, and then to obtain the value, in the `link` function you can do:

`var myPara = scope[attrs['automaticangularmodelbinding']];`

and that will contain extraParameterInFront from the parent scope.

If that parameter is just a string it is even easier:

`var myPara = attrs['automaticangularmodelbinding'];`